# Sublime Text: compiler build options

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

How can I compile `c++` code that uses dynamic or static libraries with Sublime text?

For instance:

```
#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The code above require something like:

> g++ dummy.cpp -o dummy **-lboost_filesystem**

What I want is configure Sublime text and then  when I press <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> `-lboost_filesystem` be part of the build command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lboost_filesystem"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "shell": true
}
```

and save it as `Packages/User/C++_Boost.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. Next, select `Tools -> Build System -> C++_Boost` and you should be able to build by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: I was looking at the `Sublime Text 3` interface and found out that you can go to `Tools -> Build System -> New Build system` this will create a template build system for you, that you can modify at will.